# if in partial string of an SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, sql-server-2008-r2, where-clause

I am coding a Table-valued Function in MS SQL 2008 R2.

Is it possible for a partial string of an SQL statement, which is in the WHERE clause to wrap an IF construct?

```
WHERE MyTable.MyColumn = @MyVariable
      AND (MyColumn2 = @MyVariable2)
ORDER BY MyTable.MyColumn DESC
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. If you add table structure, sample data and expected output it would be a lot easier to see what you want to do.

Comment: I want to pack the "AND (@ MyVariable2 MyColumn2 =)" in an IF construct. And the IF constuct is comparing a value with a defined variable outside of the statement. Do you know now what I mean?

Comment: Outside I have got a variable @Date and if this variable is not null I would like to expand my Where clause with the partial string "AND (MyColumn2 = @MyVariable2)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
  WHERE MyTable.MyColumn = @MyVariable
  AND ((@date is null) or (MyColumn2 = @MyVariable2))
```